# Advantages of NET::SCP over system"scp ..." or exec "scp ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there were any advantages about using the gem **Net::SCP** over using a simple --**system 'scp' '-options' "#{source}" "#{remote_host}"**--

We have more options on the second method but I feel that people wouldn't have made a NET::SCP gem if there was not a necessity.

So my questions are

- Advantages of Net::SCP over a system "command"?
- Is there a big security flaw with Ruby system shell command?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portability, for one. Windows systems don't ship with any SSH tools.

Also, ability to control behavior from code - for example, controlling policy for handling new host fingerprints is (relatively) easy with a library, but a real pain if you're executing an external process.